# fail2ban does not work for ssh except on port 22

Tags: ssh, fail2ban

My fail2ban is not working for sshd except for the default port 22/tcp.

My old, working config in jail.local:

```
[sshd]
enabled  = true
port     = ssh
```

Tested fail2ban, did ban me after 3 failed attempts as intended.

I explicitly specified a different port afterwards in jail.local; ssh tunnel works on the new port, but when I consciously err with wrong ssh password I do not receive a ban after any number of attempts.

sshd.service, fail2ban.service already restarted, also tried rebooting.

I DO get the email message about being banned, however, I can still (successfully) attempt to log in.

Edit: This is the pastebin of [fail2ban-client -d | grep 'ssh'](https://pastebin.com/p7PRztUg)

Comment: *I explicitly specified a different port afterwards in jail.local* If you use a custom ssh port, you need to explicitly set it in your conf (ex. port = 12345), otherwise fail2ban will ban on the default ssh port (22).

Comment: That is what I did. Hence my surprise.

Comment: My ban time is 10 minutes - if I change the IP for sshd to 22 and start a new tunnel for port 22, it is also not banned.

Comment: Without further information (shown configuration, logs, etc.) it is hard to guess what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something may be not correct in your configuration.

For example, fail2ban default jail section for sshd is `[sshd]`, whereas your example shows `[ssh]`. Do you have 2 jails? Or did you make some customization with own jail or defaults? (for instance default `action` is overwritten).

To inspect it deeper you could [show the dump of fail2ban (merged) configuration](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/wiki/Proper-fail2ban-configuration):

```
fail2ban-client -d | grep 'ssh'
```

Interesting are the values of actionstart (and actionban) and whether the port is interpolated in the action definitions.

Small hint: for customization (if you need to overwrite the `action` for some reason), either set the `banaction` only (it will be interpolated in default `action` declaration):

```
[jail]
banaction = iptables-ipset-proto6
```

or use [all parameters the action expects](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/4b54a07d71a6ce1c85a3eae92bace6c0dadcdcfb/config/jail.conf#L174):

```
[jail]
action = iptables-ipset-proto6[port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
```

Otherwise the action could use its default port (which may be indeed 22).

Comment: You are right with the [ssh] vs [sshd] thing. It was a typo in the post on my end, the config file has it right. I added a pastebin with the fail2ban-client -d.

Comment: See in the dump the port is `ssh`: `<iptables> -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports ssh -j f2b-sshd'`. So either you have still other configs overwriting the port of sshd jail (e. g. in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.d`, you can check which config files gets included with `fail2ban-client -vvd`) or your `jail.local` is not at right place (it must be in `/etc/fail2ban` directly) or your configs are still wrong (see my answer attentively, for instance the `action` of jail is overwritten and port specified in jail is not supplied to the action).

Comment: According to this pastebin of [fail2ban-client -vvd](https://pastebin.com/RhE44Mst) config should be fine, all ports are overwritten to 31222. My jail local was basically a copy of jail.conf copied to a jail.local in the same directory.

Comment: I cleaned up my jail.local, there it is [in whole](https://pastebin.com/qsnAhGB8).

Comment: There still many entries duplicating original jail.conf (which can be deleted), but... as regards the port, the jail.local seems to be alright. If I try dump over your config with stock `/etc/fail2ban` with `fail2ban-client -d | grep 'dports'`, it shows pretty well the correct port for `sshd` jail:<br> `['actionstart', '<iptables> -N f2b-sshd\n<iptables> -A f2b-sshd -j RETURN\n<iptables> -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 31222 -j f2b-sshd'], ['actionban', '<iptables> -I f2b-sshd 1 -s <ip> -j <blocktype>']`. So please read attentive what I wrote above and check carefully the rest of config.

Comment: ... and if your dump becomes correct (you'll see `--dports 31222`), don't forget to restart fail2ban (or at least the `sshd` jail).

Comment: Thanks, it now works properly. I had to clean up my `jail.local`some more (previously it wouldn't work even though `dports` were showing correctly already in the dump). One more thing, my `action` and `banaction` are defined by `jail.conf`. When I had overridden one of them them with `iptables-ipset-proto6` (per your comment) it would render the jail useless on all ports (incl. 22), even though `fail2ban-client status sshd` did show the ban. I cannot really tell what the differences are between them, where can I read up about it briefly? :)